# Png Image support of J2ME WTK Emulator

Tags: java, java-me, png, image-formats, java-wireless-toolkit

I use a png image in my project that is not displayed in emulator but it can be displayed in phone. Then i open it with photoshop, save as png and use that image. It is displayed both emulator and phone. I couldn't figure out the difference of original and edited one. And is there any setting of emulator for image display? And how can i understand any png file is supported or not?

[image: original image]

original image

[image: edited image]

edited image

Comment: Maybe your original image was PNG-24 rather than PNG-8? I have a similar problem to this if anyone can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484088/j2me-png-created-in-photoshop-not-displaying-in-emulator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I preferred PNG files is good for MIDP. You can check following links, It will helps you.

[What image types does MIDP support?](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/questions/imagetype/)

[Image Formats in J2ME](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/210335-image-formats-in-j2me/)

Comment: thanks for your answer links say, png is supported in midp, my question is a bit specific, some png's (original png i've uploaded in question) can't be displayed on wtk emulator, i try to find reason.