# J2ME - PNG created in PhotoShop not displaying in emulator

Tags: java-me, png, emulation, photoshop, java-wireless-toolkit

My midlet is showing some images fine, but not others.

They are all 8-bit PNGs, but the ones that aren't displaying are the ones I have created myself in PhotoShop.

So I am thinking maybe my PhotoShop (CS6) settings are wrong...

> PNG-8, Selective, Diffusion, Colors: 256, Dither: 100%, Matte: None, Web
>   Snap: 0%, Convert to sRGB: ticked, Width: 48, Height: 48, Percent: 100%,
>   Quality: Bicubic.

I've experimented with a few of these settings, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

There is a [similar problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436495/png-image-support-of-j2me-wtk-emulator) but this is opposite to mine in that PhotoShop mends things in that case, rather than breaks things...

My code is...

```
image = Image.createImage("/img/loading1.png");
```

...and here is my stack trace:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readFully(
ImageInputStreamImpl.java:353)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
    at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readUTF(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:332)
    at com.sun.kvem.png.PNGImageReader.parse_iTXt_chunk(PNGImageReader.java:447)
    at com.sun.kvem.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:650)
    at com.sun.kvem.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1312)
    at com.sun.kvem.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1582)
    at com.sun.kvem.midp.GraphicsBridge.loadImage(GraphicsBridge.java:2602)
    at com.sun.kvem.midp.GraphicsBridge.createImageFromData(GraphicsBridge.java:2511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.kvem.sublime.MethodExecution.process(MethodExecution.java:42)
    at com.sun.kvem.sublime.SublimeExecutor.processRequest(SublimeExecutor.java:63)
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.Image.createImage(Image.java:315)
```

The image in question does exist - both in the project and in the jar that is built.

Here is the image in question:
[image]

Comment: Try PNGout or Optipng tool to optimize the png before use. These tools strip out any unnecessary data and optimizes them for J2ME compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, but any idea how to use it?? I've found this tutorial but am none the wiser... http://www.advsys.net/ken/util/pngout.htm

Comment: I found another tutorial which recommends using `pngout.exe loading1.png loading1out.png`.

Comment: It looks like there is some unexpected text in an `iTxt` chunk. With Photoshop's Save for Web you can opt to not include any metadata -- try that.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks - removing the metadata has done the trick. Would you like to add that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Can you add a PNG that exhibits this particular problem to your post? I might be able to check who got it wrong -- Photoshop or J2ME -- as a background to the plain answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the crash log, the PNG decoder in J2ME fails inside the non-critical chunk `iTXt`:<sup>1</sup>

```
> com.sun.kvem.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata
  > com.sun.kvem.png.PNGImageReader.parse_iTXt_chunk
    > javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readUTF
      > java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF
```

According to [libpng documentation](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter11.html#png.ch11.div.4), the text part of an `iTXt` chunk *must* be valid UTF8:

> ... The remaining chunk data is the main UTF-8 text, either zlib-compressed or not, according to the compression flag. Since its length can be determined from the chunk length, it is not null-terminated. As with the other two text chunks, newlines should be represented by single line-feed characters (decimal 10), and all other control characters (1-9, 11-31, and 127-159) are discouraged.

and so normally this would indicate that the stream read is not valid UTF8 text - it contains 'raw' bytes higher than the plain ASCII range `0..127` that do not conform to UTF8 rules.

I found that not to be the case in the sample image. There is only one set of consecutive bytes that form a UTF8 code sequence, and it is a valid one:

```
<?xpacket begin="EFBBBF" id=" ..
```

(the bolded section represents 3 data bytes in hexadecimal notation). I first suspected this was the error:

> If the BOM character appears in the middle of a data stream, Unicode says it should be interpreted as a "zero-width non-breaking space" (inhibits line-breaking between word-glyphs). In Unicode 3.2, this usage is deprecated in favour of the "Word Joiner" character, U+2060.[1] This allows U+FEFF to be only used as a BOM.
>   (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

.. and so a fully conforming UTF8 reader should inspect its bytes and throw an `UTFDataFormatException` when it encounters a BOM anywhere else than as the very first value. Surprisingly, this does not seem to be the problem! First of all, there is no indication any of the `readUTF` sources do anything else than only verify if the UTF8 code is valid *on its own*, irrespective of its value. There are lots of 'invalid' Unicode *code points* (values that do not represent a valid Unicode character or instruction), but it appears to me they are all silently ignored. But I noticed the common `readUTF` functions only implement a small subset of UTF8/Unicode (see, e.g., [**Modified UTF-8**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8) in Oracle's documentation).

So the problem lies elsewhere. Another clue to this is that the error thrown is *not* `UTFDataFormatException` but rather `EOFException`, indicating the read buffer ran out of the number of bytes it was promised to contain.

*(warning: pure conjecture follows)*

Looking at a source of [`DataInputStream`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/DataInputStream.java.html), I find this snippet of code:

```
588       public final static String readUTF(DataInput in) throws IOException {
589           int utflen = in.readUnsignedShort();
```

followed by a loop to read `utflen` *bytes* (not "Unicode characters"). This is wrong for an `iTXt` chunk, as it does not have a 'first word' to indicate its length. The number of bytes in the plain text can be derived from the chunk length (which is, per PNG convention, the total data length excluding the length long word, the `iTXt` signature itself, and the final CRC32 code) minus the length of the zero-terminated keyword name, language, and "translated keyword" strings, and the two bytes which indicate compression of the full plain text.

---

As a work-around, remove the `iTXt` chunks from your PNG images. The data itself -- XMP Metadata -- is most likely not interesting at all for your purposes (but feel free to read [what benefits Adobe thinks it has](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp.html)). And if your workflow does not use it, it's just a useless hunk of uncompressed text, taking up 814 bytes of the total of 981 bytes in your sample image -- a whopping 83%!

You can use an external utility to remove extraneous data chunks; the command line for the popular `pngcrush`, for example, is

```
pngcrush -rem alla -rem text InputFile.png OutputFile.png
```

(from [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush)).

Or directly from Photoshop: if you save a PNG 'the usual way' with the "Save As" menu option, the metadata goes in and there is no checkbox to get rid of it. If you use "Save for Web & Devices" instead, you get a large dialog with a lot of handy options, such as a drop down list labelled "Metadata".

Choosing "All" I got an even larger file; my version of Photoshop creates a *massive* 3K chunk of XMP Metadata, including a 2K totally empty 'filler' block...
Selecting "Copyright" or "None" finally got rid of all the crud (presumably because I did not fill in any copyright information), and then you get a nice 169 bytes long PNG, in which the only metadata is that software used is called "Adobe ImageReady".

---

<sup>1</sup> Which is kind of ironic. Per PNG specifications,

> .. A decoder encountering an unknown chunk in which the ancillary bit is 1 can safely ignore the chunk and proceed to display the image.
>   ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html#Chunk-naming-conventions))

This "ancillary bit" is the 5th bit of the first byte of the chunk ID: 0 (uppercase) = critical, 1 (lowercase) = ancillary, i.e., if the first character of the chunk ID is a capital, a PNG reader *must* read and interpret its data correctly, and if it's not, it can be skipped silently.

So technically, the writers of J2ME could safely have ignored this entire chunk. But they messed it up, *attempt* to read it, and now the code crashes on all programs that merely try to read the image data in PNGs which happen to contain `iTXt` chunks.